# Match table th widths with td in wordpress

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on some styling in Wordpress with WP e-Commerce and in the checkout page there is a table in which the table headers are all getting left justified and not becoming the width of each of their columns. When I try the HTML code without the CSS it works fairly well but there is so much CSS being applied that I cannot figure out what is causing it, exactly.

Please see the HTML code in question below.

Any thoughts on how to find the culprit?

```
<table class="checkout_cart">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
            <th colspan="2">Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="product_row product_row_0 alt">
            <td class="firstcol wpsc_product_image wpsc_product_image_0">   <img src="31x31.jpg" alt="Spreading the Light" title="Light" class="product_image">   </td>
            <td class="wpsc_product_name wpsc_product_name_0">  <a href="http://hailefinephotography.com/products-page/inner-aperture-fine-art-note-cards/spreading-the-light/">Spreading the Light</a>  </td>
            <td class="wpsc_product_quantity wpsc_product_quantity_0">
                <form action="/store/checkout/" method="post" class="adjustform qty">  
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="0">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true">  
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit">  
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><span class="pricedisplay">$5.00</span></td>
            <td class="wpsc_product_price wpsc_product_price_0"><span class="pricedisplay"><span class="pricedisplay">$5.00</span></span></td>
            <td class="wpsc_product_remove wpsc_product_remove_0">
                <form action="/store/checkout/" method="post" class="adjustform remove"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="0">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true">  
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove" name="submit">  
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hard to say without the styling

Comment: But you haven't included the CSS - so how is anyone supposed to find the cause?

Comment: If the CSS is where the problem is, then the CSS is what we need to see

Comment: There are more than a dozen css files being applied. ALL the crap from Wordpress, WPEC and other plugins. I can't include them all. What I'm asking is if there are any thoughts of what could *possibly* cause the issue. Or how I might go about finding it... any good tools, etc?

Comment: so give a link on that page.

Comment: I can't... it's not live yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 headers (th), but 6 colums below (td)

Comment: The first header has colspan="2"

Comment: You are absolutely right. Missed that. But in that case I agree with hunter, Diodeus and the others.. without CSS there is nothing else we can determine..

Comment: One thing i would try to fix in any case. Was to apply inline styles on the elements in html. Inline styles override applied styles, allowing you an easy way to find out which element is messing things up. (Ofcourse your first start would be to use your browsers `inspect element` function.)